# Where should I put the crossdomain policy file in Visual Studio (CASSINI webserver)?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, silverlight

My webservice hello is defined in same solution on Visual Studio as my silverlight app. Where should I put the cross domain policy file so that I can test within Visual Studio Cassini Webserer (and not IIS):

```
public MainPage()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    WebserviceHello.HelloSoapClient Hello = new WebserviceHello.HelloSoapClient();
    Hello.getHelloCompleted += new EventHandler<WebserviceHello.getHelloCompletedEventArgs>(HelloCompleted);
    Hello.getHelloAsync();
}

public void HelloCompleted(object sender,
         WebserviceHello.getHelloCompletedEventArgs e)
{
    MessageBox.Show("success");


}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest that you look to test with IIS Express rather than Cassini. Cassini is deprecated in favour of IIS Express. IIS Express is available if you have installed Visual Studio 2010 SP1.

Comment: I have installed IIS Express but I didn't see anywhere how to use it with silverlight and webservice with cross policy domain.

Comment: I found this link that might help http://blogs.iis.net/vaidyg/archive/2011/01/21/iis-express-bootstrapper-package.aspx.